# How to link XmlElements from an object not used in JAXBContext?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Is there is any way to link or to reference the XmlElements from classes that are not used in JAXBContext when creating Marsaller?

I am using Jersey to convert the JAXB annotated object into XML file.

This is the setup I have. All classes are in the same package.

For Marsaller I use classes B, C or D

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
class A {
    private Foo foo;

    public SomeObject getSomeObjetct() {
        return foo.getSomeObjetct();
    }


    protected setFooBehavior(Foo f) {
        this.foo = f;
    }



    /* From this point the XmlElements are commond to all subclasses
     * and no other special manipulation take place.
     */  

    @XmlElement(...)
    ...someGetterMethod(){}

    @XmlElement(...)
    ...someOtherGetterMethod(){}

    @XmlElement(...)
    ...someThirdGetterMethod(){}

    ...
    ...


}

@XmlRootElement(name = "B")
class B extends A{
    setFooBehavior(new FooA());
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "C")
class C extends A{
    setFooBehavior(new FooA());
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "D")
class D extends A{
    setFooBehavior(new FooB());
}

class FooA {
    SomeObject someObject;

    @XmlElement(name = "FooA", required = true)
    public SomeObject getSomeObjetct() {
        return getSomeObjetct();
    }

    public setSomeObject(SomeObject someObject;) {
        this.someObject = SomeObject someObject;;
    }
}

class FooB {
    SomeObject someObject;

    @XmlElement(name = "FooB", required = true)
    public SomeObject getSomeObjetct() {
        return getSomeObjetct();
    }

    public setSomeObject(SomeObject someObject;) {
        this.someObject = SomeObject someObject;;
    }
}
```

and the Marsaller for every case is

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(C.class); //or B.class or D.class
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
```

At the end I want to have the following xml results

For class C

```
<C>
    <FooA>someObjectValue</FooA>
</C>
```

And for class D

```
<D>
    <FooB>someObjectValue</FooB>
</D>
```

What I get as an output now is

```
<C>
    <someObject>someObjectValue</someObject>
<C>
```

and

```
<D>
    <someObject>someObjectValue</someObject>
</D>
```

respectively.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  It looks like FooA and FooB are JAXB annotated (they both have @XmlElement on someObjetct).  What kind of error are you getting?  What isn't working?  How is the output not what you expect?

Comment: I changed the description and I wrote the output that I expect and the output that I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that someObject requires special handling in D.  Do you still have a Foo instance?  Can you do:

```
public class A {

    @XmlElementRef
    public Foo getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public SomeObject getSomeObject() {
        return foo.getSomeObject();
    }

}
```

Update: Given you cannot expose Foo then the information will have to be stored in some other mechanism.  The following solution is not great but it may serve:

```
public class A {

    private Class<?> fooType;

    //protected should be enough for JAX-B and will
    //hide the method from the rest of your code.
    @XmlAnyElement
    protected JAXBElement<SomeObject> getSomeObjetctForJaxb() {
        return new JAXBElement<SomeObject>(new QName(fooType.getSimpleName()), SomeObject.class, getSomeObjetct());
    }

}
```

Do you need to unmarshal the XML as well?  If so you'll need a setter that takes in a `JAXBElement<SomeObject>` and will have to create the Foo appropriately based on the name of the element.

Comment: Yes I always have a Foo instance.Unfortunately I can't return foo from A! Foo is used to simulate different behavior for someObject. Returning foo, demands to change code in a big part of the project.
Acctually at FooA someObject is a single instance of an object and at FooB someObject is a list of the same object.
But nobody should know that except FooA and FooB.
And of course there is the posibility of new subclasses of A that can have either the single object or the list behavior.

Comment: Ok, tried again.  I'm afraid this class structure seems somewhat complicated.  Not knowing enough about your code the best I can come up with is that this feels like a case where composition may serve better than inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It solved my problem. I changed the getSomeObject method in class A to return a JAXBElement. I was trying to solve it with XmlElementRef with no luck... Btw the structure I gave above is exactly what I have. I just changed the names :D ! Again thanks a lot!